# Using R2WinBUGS, how to extract information from each chain?

Tags: r, markov-chain-montecarlo, bugs

I am new to Gibbs Sampling, and have been using WinBUGS, but I find that it is not well-suited towards storing/presenting results, so I have been calling it from R using the R2WinBUGS package.  The data is apparently stored as a "bug" class.

I converted it to coda to run diagnostics, and it displays each of the chains, but I am confused as to the $ extension for each individual chain.  I cannot find any good documentation for the "coda" class (the cran instructions are not helpful).

My code is below:

```
> bugs.sim <- bugs(data, inits, parameter, "gl.bug", n.chains = 5,
                   codaPkg = TRUE, DIC = FALSE, n.iter = 5000)
> codaobject <- read.bugs(bugs.sim)
```

As you can see, I have 5 chains, and I would like to take the mean and standard deviation of each.  How do I go about doing this?  I can use the codaobject to take the [Geweke diagnostic](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~plam/teaching/methods/convergence/convergence_print.pdf) of each chain, it displays each chain as `[[i]]` ($i=1,\dots,5$).

Thanks in advance.  And any references to a detailed documentation for R2Winbugs, would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean something like http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~plam/teaching/methods/convergence/convergence_print.pdf ?

Comment: I looked through that exact link last night actually, which was what prompted me to convert my bugs output to CODA, but from what I can see, they aren't calling WinBUGS, they are using a built in function in R's MCMC package.

Comment: You can also use my function read.winbugs(): ["Storing WinBUGS output"](ftp://ftp.cirad.fr/pub/group-r/groupe-r/Fiches/WinBUGS_reading_v3.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object returned by `read.bugs` is an object of S3 class `mcmc.list`. 
You can use the double brackets `[[` to access the separate chains, i.e. the different `mcmc`-objects that make up the larger `mcmc.list` object, which really is simply a list of `mcmc`-objects that inherits some information about thinning and chain length from its components.

More to the point, s.th. like `lapply(codaobject, function(x){ colMeans(x) })` should return the posterior means for each parameter in each chain and `lapply(codaobject, function(x){ apply(x, 2, sd) })` should give chain- and parameter-specific posterior sd's, since each chain is essentially just a numeric matrix with rows corresponding to the (saved) iterations and columns corresponding to the different params.

EDIT:
I think Gelman/Hill's "Bayesian Data Analysis" contains some worked examples using R2WinBUGS.

Comment: Thanks! That is just what I need.  I have "Bayesian Data Analysis" and I will take a closer look for the worked examples.

Comment: (+1) E.g. [Example of computation in R and Bugs](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/bugsR/software.pdf) (Online Appendix C of BDA).

Answer (score 2):

The contents of your chains are stored in three different formats.  Take a look at

```
bugs.sim$sims.array
bugs.sim$sims.list
bugs.sim$sims.matrix
```

and read the Value section of `?bugs`.